# Google Map API: Searching through text in infowindow possible?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working on an application where various markers are placed with infowindows on a Google Map based on a user's posts. I've also included geocoding so that the user can change their location and view markers/posts in any area.

What I'd like to do is for the user to search through the text info in the infowindows via a form and the map then responds by showing the markers that contain that text window. I've searched through the API and I don't see this ability mentioned, although it seems like it should be achievable.

Any insight or information on how to accomplish this would be much appreciated.

Here's the current code within the application:

```
function mainGeo()
{
     if (navigator.geolocation) 
        {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( mainMap, error, {maximumAge: 30000, timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true} );
    }
    else
    {
          alert("Sorry, but it looks like your browser does not support geolocation.");
    }
}


var stories = {{storyJson|safe}};
var geocoder;
var map;


function loadMarkers(stories){
    for (i=0;i<stories.length;i++) {
        var story = stories[i];

        (function(story) {
            var pinColor = "69f2ff";
                var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=S|" + pinColor,
                    new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(story.latitude, story.longitude);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, map: map, icon: pinImage});
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<div >'+
                '<div >'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h2 class="firstHeading">'+story.headline+'</h2>'+
                '<div>'+
                '<p>'+story.author+'</p>'+
                '<p>'+story.city+'</p>'+
                '<p>'+story.topic+'</p>'+
                '<p>'+story.date+'</p>'+
                '<p>'+story.copy+'</p>'+
                '<p><a href='+story.url+'>Click to read story</a></p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'

          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,this);
          });
        })(story);
    }
}



 function mainMap(position)
 {
       geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       // Define the coordinates as a Google Maps LatLng Object
       var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);


       // Prepare the map options
       var mapOptions =
      {
                  zoom: 15,
                  center: coords,
                  mapTypeControl: false,
                  navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        // Create the map, and place it in the map_canvas div
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        // Place the initial marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: coords,
                  map: map,
                  title: "Your current location!"
        });

        loadMarkers(stories);

    }


  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }


function error() {
    alert("You have refused to display your location. You will not be able to submit stories.");
    }

mainGeo();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create three empty arrays (e.g., `markers`, `infowindows`, and `matches`)
2. As you instantiate the marker, reference the marker via an index in the `markers` array (e.g., `markers[i] = marker`)
3. As you instantiate the infowindow, reference it's content via an index in the `infowindows` array (e.g., `infowindows[i] = htmltext` [or whatever variable name you store your content in)
4. Search for the string in the `infowindows` array, store the indexes of the items that contain the string in the `matches` array, and then use a for loop with the `matches` array to add the markers from the `markers` array (based on the index values of the `matches` array).

Comment: Thanks. Not sure exactly where to place this within the current code.